# R – How to calculate combinations of pairs?

Tags: r, combinatorics

From a number of items (n), how do I compute all possible combinations of pairs in R? I can calculate the number of possible combinations with `(n-1)*(n-3)*(n-5)*…`, but how to get the combinations themselves?

For example, I have

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

That would make `4-1=3` combinations of pairs, so I want to have something like

```
("AB","CD")
("AC","BD")
("AD","BC")
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: see the combn function https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.1/topics/combn

Comment: There are several packages for this type of thing... Just type [combinations in R](https://www.google.com/search?ei=OoopWvyrBIHTmwH0wYfAAw&q=combinations+in+R&oq=combinations+in+R&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i7i30k1l4j0l4j0i5i30k1.6997.8251.0.9228.2.2.0.0.0.0.92.156.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.156...0i22i30k1.0.khYQ1iyLwhw) into Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's get all pairs of pairs:

```
dat = t(combn(combn(x, 2, paste, collapse=""), 2))
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2]
>  [1,] "AB" "AC"
>  [2,] "AB" "AD"
>  [3,] "AB" "BC"
>  [4,] "AB" "BD"
>  [5,] "AB" "CD"
>  [6,] "AC" "AD"
>  [7,] "AC" "BC"
>  [8,] "AC" "BD"
>  [9,] "AC" "CD"
> [10,] "AD" "BC"
> [11,] "AD" "BD"
> [12,] "AD" "CD"
> [13,] "BC" "BD"
> [14,] "BC" "CD"
> [15,] "BD" "CD"
> ```

We now have all pairs of pairs. But it looks like you want only pairs of pairs where each letter appears only once. The code below identifies rows that meet this condition (though it seems like the code is more complicated than it needs to be).

```
dat[sapply(strsplit(apply(dat, 1, paste, collapse=""), ""), function(i) length(unique(i)) == 4), ]
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2]
> [1,] "AB" "CD"
> [2,] "AC" "BD"
> [3,] "AD" "BC"
> ```

Comment: Maybe he wants `apply(dat, 1, paste0, collapse = "")` after creating the dataframe.

Comment: You don't need the line `apply(combn(x,2), 2, paste, collapse="")` as `combn` takes functions. E.g. `combn(x, 2, paste, collapse ="")`

Comment: Great, that was exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For that you can use either `combn` or `expand.grid`

```
x <- c("A","B","C","D") 

expand.grid(x, x) # generates both way combinations

   Var1 Var2
1     A    A
2     B    A
3     C    A
4     D    A
5     A    B
6     B    B
7     C    B
8     D    B
9     A    C
10    B    C
11    C    C
12    D    C
13    A    D
14    B    D
15    C    D
16    D    D

t(combn(x, 2)) # order does not matter

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "C" 
[3,] "A"  "D" 
[4,] "B"  "C" 
[5,] "B"  "D" 
[6,] "C"  "D"
```